# CommandLineRunner and Springboot issue with Hibernate - could not initialize proxy session - no session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, soap

I have created a Soap service in spring-boot using the following blog 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/07/writing-consuming-soap-webservice-spring.html

The Endpoint Publish Url

```
@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      Endpoint.p
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9000" +"/service/serve", new ServeWeb());

}
```

The WebService Class is as follows

```
@WebService
public class ServeWeb {

    @Autowired
    XyzService xyzService;


    @WebMethod(operationName="LOGIN")
    public List<String> userLogin(
            @WebParam(name = "uid")String uid, 
            @WebParam(name = "pwd")String pwd){ 

           System.out.println("uid == "+uid+"::::: pwd == "+pwd);
            List<String> userDetaillist =xyzService.userLogin(uid, pwd);
        return userDetaillist;
    }
}
```

In XyzService I am using

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

I am getting following Exception  on console

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

The issue is with CommandLinerRunner and Spring Boot Entity Manager. Can anyone let me know how we could use same entity manger through command line runner

Answer (score 2):

I have fond the solution , I have used Spring annotation @Transactional on the XyzService and it worked for me.